# SharePoint 2010 Calculated Field Difference in hours between two dates

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column

Using this formula

```
=INT(([Approver Action Time]-[Approval Submission Time])*24)
```

But if Approver Action Time is empty I don't want a crazy negative value just a blank

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IF statement, very much like in Excel. Try

```
=IF([Approver Action Time]>0,INT(([Approver Action Time]-[Approval Submission Time])*24),"")
```

Comment: interesting I still get some fields with minus signs

Comment: I corrected the formula. I put the wrong field into the comparison. Now, you will still get negative numbers if the Approval Submission Time value is greater than the Approver Action Time. If that kind of entry should not be allowed, you need to use validation in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(
OR(ISBLANK([Approval Submission Time]), ISBLANK([Approver Action Time]), 
[Approval Submission Time]>[Approver Action Time]), 
0,INT(([Approver Action Time]-[Approval Submission Time])*24))
```